# Change Columns From String to Date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I used this code:
"df$started_at <- mdy(df$started_at)" to change the data type of string to date but it is not working.
Error Message:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, started_at, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 10.

Sample of the Data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(19180, 19210, 19240, 
19270,19300, 19330), class = "Date"), year = c("2022", 
"2022", "2022","2022", "2022", "2022"), month = c("07", 
"08", "09", "10", "11","12"), Month = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Day = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA,6L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

New code new error:

```
new_df <- df %>%
df %>% 
mutate(
year = year(date),
month = month(date),
day = day(date)    
) %>% select(date, year, month, day)
```

New Error:
Error in df(.) : argument "df1" is missing, with no default

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible data set, perhaps by pasting the output of the command `dput(head(df))` as part of your question?

Comment: What? Sorry I am lost. I posted the error message and the code I used what more do I post?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would provide a sample of your data

Comment: Okay, I get what you are saying. Hold on let me edit it! Thank you.

Comment: Ok I included the dput(head(df))

Comment: Got the data. But in your code I see that you are trying to change the `started_at` column but in your data there is no such column. Would you specify what you want to do actually more clearly, thank you.

Comment: So I am trying to change the started_at data into a date format to separate Month, Day, and Year into separate columns. I think I got the code for MDY correctly to separate but it isn't letting me because the dates aren't formatted into a Date data type. At this point, I may skip this step and move to something else but I need to go back to it because I think it will matter when creating the visuals.

Comment: You do not need to specify `df` twice. Please see my post edit

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(
        year = year(date),
        month = month(date),
        day = day(date)
    ) %>%
    select(date, year, month, day)

#>         date year month day
#> 1 2022-07-07 2022     7   7
#> 2 2022-08-06 2022     8   6
#> 3 2022-09-05 2022     9   5
#> 4 2022-10-05 2022    10   5
#> 5 2022-11-04 2022    11   4
#> 6 2022-12-04 2022    12   4
```

Comment: @AndreaPerez, What I have understood from your comments, is this you want to do ?

Comment: See I did do that and got the same result but how do I make this so that it will change my data set it just outputs information. I am trying to change the actual data set. Do I run a script because I've done that.

Comment: store this data as another data.frame with `<-` like `new_df <- df %>% ..... `

Comment: "Error in df(.) : argument "df1" is missing, with no default" Now this error comes up.

Comment: Please show your code by editing the original question so that we could understand what you are trying and understand the error better.